# Writing a command line helper utility with access to a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a standalone app that is self composed and has some data (task lists). I'm now looking to supplement this data with an outside source (the Asana API).

I was looking to implement this as a command-line tool that is invoked by cron. However, I can't seem to be able to figure out how to get access to my Rails environments from the script.

So, the question would be: how do I get the functionality to get and manipulate models from within a simple ruby script inside `{app_root}/bin/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
require '/path/to/app/config/application'
MyApp::Application.instance.initialize!
# now you have access to your app environment
```

But usually this is solved by creating a rake task in your application that you can run by CRON.